# Modular group maps upper half to itself in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $U$ is upper half complex plane:
Suppose $$H=\{{{az+b\over cz+d}:a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R, ad-bc \gt0}\} $$ be set of modular group. Now I have to prove $H=Aut(U)$

I have some ideas, I was trying to map upper half to disc by some cayley transfrom and mobius map from disc to disc lastly again inverse cayley tranform from disc to uppper half. but i don't know how to do explicitly.
I would appreciate if you show me proof.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose Im$\,z>0\;$ , then

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\cdot\frac{c\overline z+d}{c\overline z+d}=\frac{ab|z|^2+(ad+bc)\text{Re}\,z+(ad-bc)\text{Im}\,zi+bd}{|cz+d|^2}$$

and the imaginary part of the last expression above is

$$\frac{(ad-bc)\,\text{Im}\,z}{|cz+d|^2}>0$$

Comment: yes, it maps upper half to upper half but how does it proves the automorpism?

Comment: It's easy to show that each element of the modular group is injective, but you can also show it has an inverse map: $$-\frac{dz-b}{cz-a}$$